# Loading jsp page using jQuery .load() causes issue

Tags: ajax, jquery, document-ready, jspinclude

I load a div dynamically with jquery .load() function. I am calling a jsp in which I I performing an operation on `window.onload = function() { //some operation}`  and `$(window).unload(function(){//some operation; anotherFunction();})`

Now, the problem is that these operations are not being executed, but the call to `anotherFunction()` is made! I simply put an alert() before the function call and the alert won't fire, whereas the alert that I put inside `anotherfunction()` will be fired.

I have some javascript code that I have written in `$(document).ready(function(){//some javascript code;})`. None of my operation in the ready() function gets done when I load the jsp using .load().

all the above operations are working fine when I use `<jsp:include page="myPage.jsp"></jsp:include>`

does anyone have any idea why .load() would work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with JSP isn't great but I know a fair bit about Javascript and PHP so I assume this will work on a similar principle.

Are you using an onClick listener so for example `$("SELECTOR").click(function(){`

If so then I think try this for example instead:

`$(document).on('click', "SELECTOR", function() {`